# Condition in pivot expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to use greater than in pivot expresion? For example:

```
SELECT
    MONTH
  , col1
  , col2
FROM
(
   SELECT month, c1, c2, date1 FROM table1
)
PIVOT
(
   SUM(c1)
   FOR(c2, date1) IN
   (
        ('x', < SYSDATE)  AS col1
      , ('x', >= SYSDATE) AS col2
   )
);
```

I need to have columns depends from sysdate.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  It is a little unclear what you want to do, but this should be close:

```
select month,
       sum(case when date1 < sysdate then c1 else 0 end) as col1,
       sum(case when date1 >= sysdate then c1 else 0 end) as col2
from table1 t1
group by month
```